# Can the twisted web client make requests through a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, twisted, socks, tor

I'm writing a python program that uses twisted.web.client.Agent to make https requests. I'd like to optionally make these requests through Tor, which I should be able to do if I set my socks5 proxy to 127.0.0.1:9050.

I can't find any twisted documentation on using socks proxies, but I can find info about using http proxies: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html#auto9

I've also found some code in another project, ooni-probe, that seems to be making twisted web requests through a socks proxy. Here's the Agent:

https://gitweb.torproject.org/ooni-probe.git/blob/HEAD:/ooni/templates/httpt.py#l65

```
self.control_agent = Agent(reactor, sockshost="127.0.0.1",
                           socksport=config.tor.socks_port)
```

But that Agent is actually ooni.utils.txagentwithsocks.Agent, inherited from twisted.web.client.Agent:

https://gitweb.torproject.org/ooni-probe.git/blob/HEAD:/ooni/utils/txagentwithsocks.py#l157

The request method there looks like this:

```
def request(self, method, uri, headers=None, bodyProducer=None):
    if (uri.startswith('shttp') or uri.startswith('httpo')) and not HTTPConnectionPool:
        log.err("Requests over SOCKS are supported only with versions of Twisted >= 12.1.0")
        raise UnsupportedTwistedVersion
    return client.Agent.request(self, method, uri, headers, bodyProducer)
```

It seems like Twisted >= 12.1.0 supports socks proxies, right? Does anyone know how to make requests through them without writing a child class of twisted.web.client.Agent?

Answer (score 4):

The `twisted.web.client.Agent` API in Twisted does not support SOCKS.  This is a planned, but as yet unimplemented, feature.

If you wanted to speed this along, you could encourage the OONI project to contribute their implementation upstream.

Comment: I'm not an OONI dev, but would be interested to see this happen. Do you mean the txsocksx project? Or something else? What would be required to get this into Twisted?

Comment: I think I suggested interacting with the OONI project, since it looks like they're the ones who have an `Agent` that supports SOCKS.  Does it depend on txsocksx?  Getting this into Twisted just requires that the authors (actually the copyright holders :/) be willing to contribute it to the project under an appropriate license, and that the code be well tested and documented (and work ;).  The Twisted development process is outlined at http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/ReviewProcess

Comment: Hi, I am an OONI developer and the author of txsocksx. Currently to have support for SOCKS in the t.w.client.Agent you do need txsocksx. I have however written a patch to t.w.client.Agent that allows you to wrap endpoints with an arbitrary endpoint. This would enable you to use the Agent with any SOCKS client that implements an endpoint: https://github.com/hellais/twisted/commit/412d908b94ee5f6962ea36e5e5b9a1f3876c9d62.

I would also be very happy to have txsocksx merged into twisted, it however depends on parsley and I am not sure twisted is willing to add that as a dependency.

Comment: Just responding to the last bit - there is a GSoC this summer to improve a bunch of protocol implementations in Twisted by using parsley.  So I don't think a parsley dependency should be a problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

With my library "txtorcon" you can easily create an `Agent` suitable for use with the built-in Twisted web client (or treq) that can make requests over Tor (or over a selected circuit).

See: https://txtorcon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#making-connections-over-tor

txtorcon now includes its own minimal SOCKS5 client for two reasons: txsocksx doesn't (and probably won't?) support Python3 and Tor has a few custom SOCKS5 opcodes (for DNS lookups) and may add more in the future.